# DAX divide each row value with the result of a cumulative sum

Tags: dax, measure, cumulative-sum

I have two tables that contain the number of users of two types (see picture).

[image: Tables]

[image: Table_1]

[image: Table_2]

I have created a measure that computes the cumulative sum of the number of Users2

```
TotalUsers2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Users_2[Users_2] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( Users_2 ),
        'Users_2'[Year_month] <= MAX ( 'Users_2'[Year_month] )
    )
)
```

I would like to divide each row of table 1 with the rows of TotalUsers2.

For example, for `2019_01`, I have 10 `Users1` and 1000 in the `totalUsers2`, I want to obtain the 10/1000 * 100 value.

For `2019_02`, 20/1500 * 100, for `2019_03`, 30/1700 * 100, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that measure in the denominators, except you'll need to use `Users_1[Year_month]` instead of `Users_2[Year_month]` for the `MAX`.

```
TotalUsers2 =
DIVIDE (
    SUM ( Users_1[Users_1] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Users_2[Users_2] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( Users_2 ),
            Users_2[Year_month] <= MAX ( Users_1[Year_month] )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!